# undefined method for nil:NilClass - Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Could some explain to me why I may well be getting the following error every time I try to create a booking.

```
NoMethodError in BookingsController#create

undefined method `diary_slot_day_time_path' for nil:NilClass
```

I have the following code in my controller:

```
class BookingsController < PortalController

  # GET /bookings
  # GET /bookings.json
  def index

    session[:booking_context] = 'index'

    if current_user.is_booking_manager? 
    #  @bookings = Booking.all
    # @bookings = Booking.filter(params[:search], [:reference_number, :company_id])
     @bookings = Booking.includes(:company).filter(params[:search], [:reference_number, "companies.name"])
    @main_heading = 'Bookings'
    else
      @bookings = current_user.company.bookings
    @main_heading = "#{current_user.company.name} Bookings"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
    end
  end

  # GET /bookings/1
  def show
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    goto_booking(@booking)
  end

  # GET /bookings/1/edit
  def edit
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    @main_heading = 'Edit Booking'
  end

  # Go to booking
  def goto_booking(booking)

    site = @booking.site
    slot_day = @booking.slot_day
    slot_time = @booking.slot_time

    # don't need to check slot_time because it is optional
    if session[:booking_context] and session[:booking_context] == 'diary' and site and slot_day
      # Go the diary page
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to diary_slot_day_time_path(site, slot_day, slot_time) }
      end
    else

      # Go to booking edit page
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to edit_booking_path(@booking) }
      end
    end
  end

  # POST /bookings
  def create
    @booking = Booking.new(params[:booking])
    unless @booking and @booking.slot_time and @booking.slot_time.number_of_free_slots > 0
      flash[:notice] = 'Slot no longer available'
      redirect_to :back
      return
    end

    if @booking.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Booking was successfully created'
      goto_booking(@booking)
    else
      @main_heading = 'Review New Booking'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /bookings/1
  def update
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    if @booking.update_attributes(params[:booking])
      flash[:notice] = 'Booking was successfully updated'
      goto_booking(@booking)
    else
      @main_heading = 'Review Booking'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    end
  end

  def confirmation
    begin
      @booking = Booking.find(params[:booking][:id])
      @booking.update_attributes(params[:booking])
      if params[:make_unexpected]
        @booking.provisional_appointment = nil
        @booking.save!
      end
      @booking.update_slot!
      success = true
    rescue => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      success = false
    end

    if success
      flash[:notice] = 'Booking confirmed'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to booking_path(@booking) }
      end      
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  # DELETE /bookings/1
  def destroy
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])

    if @booking
      if session[:booking_context] and session[:booking_context] == 'diary'
        site = @booking.site
        slot_day = @booking.slot_day
        slot_time = @booking.slot_time
      end

      if @booking.destroy
        flash[:notice] = 'booking removed'
      else
        flash[:error] = 'could not remove booking'
      end
    end

    # don't need to check slot_time; that's optional
    if site and slot_day

      # redirect to diary page
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to diary_slot_day_time_path(site, slot_day, slot_time) }
      end
    else

      # redirect to booking index
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to bookings_url }
      end
    end
  end

  def diary_slot_day_time_path(*args)
    @template.diary_slot_day_time_path(*args)
  end

end
```

I think that potentially it is something to do with a routing error I may well be wrong. This is my full trace error: [Pastie](http://pastie.org/3487283). I have looked at the trace which indicates to me that there is something wrong with my `go_to_booking`, `create` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have this method defined at the bottom of your controller?

```
def diary_slot_day_time_path(*args)
  @template.diary_slot_day_time_path(*args)
end
```

This is attempting to reference an undefined instance variable called `@template`, which is why you're getting that error.

You should be defining this method in your routes, by using nested routes like this:

```
match '/diary/:day/:time', :to => "some_controller#some_action", :as => "diary_slot_day_time"
```

Comment: The reason is that is calls the helper through the template/view_context. But for some reason @template isn't working. Usually helpers are to inaccessible to controller because they are for views. So my question now is where would you put custom path methods? In the lib or model?

Comment: No, why? You shouldn't be doing this. The controller has the routing helpers available to it.